# Most efficient way to make a list/array of size 500,000 with elements randomly generated from 0-15? (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out what would be the most efficient way to create a list or array of size 500,000 with its elements being numbers randomly generated from 0-15.

I know that this would be easily achievable with a for loop appending random values to the list, but given that its size is so large I would like to avoid having this O(n) runtime.

Would there be a faster way to do this, perhaps using numpy?

Comment: Avoiding O(n) runtime when generating and storing n values?!

Comment: Generating n numbers is O(N) time and O(N) Space

Comment: I believe append is not `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.random.randint(0,16,n)` to create an array of size `n` with elements between `0-15`